# accessing file name with find module of ansible

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I am using the find module in ansible to get the first file (on a remote server) that matches the pattern I have mentioned in the find module.  I am getting an exception in the debug message - should I be using another mechanism to achieve this?

```
  find: paths="/home/ubuntu/" patterns="*.deb"
  register: test_build

- debug: msg={{ test_build.files.0.path }}
  shell: dpkg -i {{ test_build.files.0.path }}
  become: True
  become_user: root 
  become_method: sudo
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what this question is about (you did not show the error message), but the playbook excerpt you included contains simple syntax errors (two tasks are squeezed into one). Fixing them makes the tasks work:

```
- find: paths="/home/ubuntu/" patterns="*.deb"
  register: test_build

- debug: msg={{ test_build.files.0.path }}

- shell: dpkg -i {{ test_build.files.0.path }}
  become: True
  become_user: root 
  become_method: sudo
```

Comment: I made a copy/paste mistake - the find module is used in a different task.  The issue was that test_build.files.0.path was returning an error (will add the error message tomorrow)